# Windows Azure Caching (Preview) ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0006>:

Tags: windows, azure

I'm using the role-based caching feature for a windows azure web role. 
Configured as co-located. I've followed the steps given by windows azure docs for caching (preview). I get the following error:

> ErrorCode <ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0006>:There is a temporary failure.
>   Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are
>   unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For
>   on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions.
>   Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client
>   account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed
>   through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the
>   server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size
>   sent from the client.). Additional Information : The client was trying
>   to communicate with the server: net.tcp://127.255.0.4:20010/.

I'm running everything as localhost, using the local development storage, my cache client is in the same role as the server. Changed many configuration attributes, but I always get that excpection or similar like "cannot connect to tcp....".

I'd appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things which could go wrong with your application.

Very first thing to make sure that you have SDK 1.7 in your machine even with Windows Azure Caching Services and then verify that you have reference set from Windows Azure Cache (not from Windows Server App Fabric SDK). I have seen such misconfiguration in past which lead to such errors.

Now have you changed your dataCacheClient, identifier to your ROLE Name as described in the documentation link [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/). If you follow the documentation as described to you should not hit any error so for the sake of checking what could be wrong, you can create exact same application as described in this link and see if that works or not.

To get more details error, please be sure to increase the DataCacheFactoryConfiguration.ChannelOpenTimeout value to longer i.e. 2 minutes then default 20 seconds as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akshar/archive/2011/05/01/azure-appfabric-caching-errorcode-lt-errca0017-gt-substatus-lt-es0006-gt-what-to-do.aspx). This step will help you to get details about inner exception which may lead to actual root cause to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I'll check them out

Answer (score 1):

We use Azure co-located caching (not in preview anymore) as our session backer and have fairly regular outages. About once a month.

We tried using the Enterprise library [Transient Fault Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680905%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) but our instances still hang when caching experiences problems. I think that the transient fault code would work for data caching, but for session backing there is some activity closer to the metal that we can't seem to code against.

The error codes have become more informative over the last year and go something like...

> ErrorCode:SubStatus:The request timed out..
>   Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the
>   server: net.tcp://10.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx/.

Our best guess so far from experimenting and MS support is that each, or at least one co-located cache role/instance needs to know about all the other instance's IPs, since Azure can destroy and re-up instances whenever they want, this sometimes fails to update the dependent instances. This is secret sauce for Azure, but it is not a secret when our site goes down. I'm looking for any more information on this and to see how others are working around this issue.

**One possible work-around.** One of our talented platform administrators found that resetting IIS on the instances and scaling up two more instances seem to help the problem. This makes sense to me because it gives caching another chance to gather all the required info about the other instances. This is NOT CONFIRMED to solve the problem but if we repeat this during the next outage it could be a valid work around.

Comment: did you guys make any other progress on this? Did your workaround above work?

Comment: That work around has worked on one occasion and we have not had another opportunity to try it again. We did have some more MS training for Azure and learned to make sure we have at least 3 dedicated cache instances running since they can pull instances offline to update them based on an update zone.  We are definitely not pursuing azure sql as a session backer for performance and reliability reasons.